# Determine if the following is an inner product on the given vector space:

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

V = P2 : **p**, **q** = a0b0 − a1b1 + a2b2, with p(x) = a0 + a1x + a2x
2
, q(x) =
b0 + b1x + b2x
2
, x ∈ R.

Is this an inner product on the given vector space ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial.  You got a couple down votes, probably because you didn't show effort.  Do you know what are the conditions for an inner product?

Answer (score 0):

No , positivity axiom does not hold.

Counter example : p(x) = 1 +2x + x^2

Hence < **p** , **p** > = -2